How to know disclosure QRect in QStyledItemDelegate in sizeHint() method?
I implementing a custom QStyledItemDelegate and want to know disclosure QRect in sizeHint() method to calculate correct size hint for my items.
I tried:
QSize
WordWrapItemDelegate::sizeHint( const QStyleOptionViewItem & option,
    const QModelIndex & index ) const
{
    QStyleOptionViewItem opt = option;
    initStyleOption( &opt, index );
    opt.rect = { 0, 0, m_parent->header()->sectionSize( index.column() ), 0 };
    
    QStyle * style = opt.widget ? opt.widget->style() : QApplication::style();
    auto iconRect = style->subElementRect( QStyle::SE_TreeViewDisclosureItem, &opt, opt.widget );
    
    qDebug() << iconRect;
    
    return option.fontMetrics.boundingRect(
        QRect( 0, 0,
            m_parent->header()->sectionSize( index.column() ) -
                option.decorationSize.width() /** level * 2*/, 0 ),
        Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::TextWordWrap,
        index.data( Qt::DisplayRole ).toString() ).size();
}

And:
QSize
WordWrapItemDelegate::sizeHint( const QStyleOptionViewItem & option,
    const QModelIndex & index ) const
{
    int level = 1;
    auto i = index;
    
    while( i.parent().isValid() )
    {
        ++level;
        i = i.parent();
    }
    
    return option.fontMetrics.boundingRect(
        QRect( 0, 0,
            m_parent->header()->sectionSize( index.column() ) -
                option.decorationSize.width() * level * 2, 0 ),
        Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::TextWordWrap,
        index.data( Qt::DisplayRole ).toString() ).size();
}

The second variant works, but, as you can see, I use some hard-coding option.decorationSize.width() * level * 2.
In the first variant I always get the same rectangle as in options.
Do anybody know how to know the width of the disclosure in item?

I was completely wrong in understanding QStyle stuff. Disclosure width can be given with the following code.
QSize
WordWrapItemDelegate::sizeHint( const QStyleOptionViewItem & option,
    const QModelIndex & index ) const
{       
    const auto w = QApplication::style()->pixelMetric( QStyle::PM_TreeViewIndentation );
    
    int level = 1;
    auto i = index;
    
    while( i.parent().isValid() )
    {
        ++level;
        i = i.parent();
    }
    
    return option.fontMetrics.boundingRect(
        QRect( 0, 0, m_parent->header()->sectionSize( index.column() ) - w * level, 0 ),
        Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::TextWordWrap,
        index.data( Qt::DisplayRole ).toString() ).size();
}

Pay attention that I use style()->pixelMetric( QStyle::PM_TreeViewIndentation ) that returns width of one level disclosure. And I forced to calculate nesting level and multiply by it.
And that's all. This is a correct solution.
Do know that in paint() method in options rectangle is with that offset already, it's calculated somewhere. So if your item has a rectangle { 0, 0, 200, 30} in paint() method you will have the rectangle, for example, { 40, 0, 160, 30 }.
